# Update assembly version in MS Build only if code changed

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I am new to MSBuild. I am wrote inline script where I am able to increase assembly version. I am successfully able to update assemblyinfo.cs file

This task will every time increase assembly version even without code change. Is there any way to check in MSBuild script not to increase assembly version in assemblyinfo.cs file if there is no code change.

In my Visual studio solution there are multiple project, so I needs to only update those project's dll on which some code changed.

Comment: not only code changes define if your assembly is changed. Even if you do not change a loc, a change in a dependent assembly ( for instance changing a member method to static or changing a method to be virtual, changing a referenced constant value in another assembly) means a version change. What we did to achieve this was to implement an after build task to compare disassembled IL of the generated and old versions of the same assemblies and to remove the unchanged assemblies from the deployment package. Only changed assemblies then will have new versions.

Comment: you can then rollback the version increment for the unchanged assemblies. This was frankly a hard task which was only implemented because our customer asked for only changed assemblies to be deployed and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you Oguz Ozgul for your helpful comment, but still I have to look at how can I implement?

Comment: I know it is bit older question but I am looking for the same kind of solution. Did you find the answer ?

Comment: @Tatipaka Yes I found the solution. I have added my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am able solve the above question by following code

Basically we need to override target, this targets get called by MSBuild when there is any code change is detected (basically MSBuild will detect based on changed date timestamp of assembly)

> BeforeCompile

You can go through the list of inbuilt property and item-group which Microsoft provides.

[List of inbuilt property and itemgroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2017)

```
<Target Name="BeforeCompile"
      Inputs="@(Compile);
        @(ReferencePath);
        $(MSBuildAllProjects);"
      Outputs="@(IntermediateAssembly)">

  ***** ADD YOUR CUSTOM CODE HERE ****

</Target>
```